# svelte-kit: How should I specify the version?

Tags: svelte, package.json, sveltekit

In `package.json`, should I use:

> "@sveltejs/kit": "next",

or

> "@sveltejs/kit": "1.0.0-next.377",

Does `next` means always use the latest version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think `next` branch as the beta branch of the releases. It can have numbered subreleases.

For the codebase stability you should always use a numbered release. Because SvelteKit APIs are unstable, otherwise a simple `npm install` might break your application.

Comment: I decided to use `next` in development to get easy upgration, If I see issues, might switch to numbered release before deploy to production.

Comment: I strongly suggest agaist this, because upgrading SvelteKt can be a separate command (in fact documentation offers some hints how to do this).

Comment: Probably you're right for production, but there also need some people to use the newest version to discover bugs quickly, e.g https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/5672

Answer (score 0):

Now svelte-kit has released v1, can use:

> "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.7",